# Cant add x86_64 support to the static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, bash, architecture, static-libraries

i'v been working for hours for this 'little' problem.I tried to create a universal library and i managed to get 3 set of architecture, when i check my universal lib with lipo -info

```
 armv7 i386 arm64
```

and with file command

```
Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures

(for architecture armv7):   current ar archive random library
(for architecture i386):    current ar archive random library
(for architecture arm64):   current ar archive random library
```

my shell script to create universal lib ;

```
# define output folder environment variable
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target libTest ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

xcodebuild -target libTest ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 2. Create universal binary file using lipo
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"

# Last touch. copy the header files. Just for convenience
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/include" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
```

my build settings;

```
build active architecture only - NO

Architectures;

$(ARCHS_STANDARD)
x86_64 (i added this)

Valid architectures;
armv7s
x86_64
armv7
arm64
i386
```

I tried everything and it still seems failed.How can I create a fat file with all these architectures?

Comment: What's the minimum iOS version in settings ?

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood the deployment target you mean? ios deployment target in the settings is ios 7.0

Comment: Simplify your problem, can you get any 2 archs including `x86_64` to create a fat file? Good luck!

Comment: and.. aren't you getting any error messages? If so, selectively add the most relevant to your  post above.